# MVC : How to avoid url encoding in ActionLink mapRoute Params

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-encode

In my view I have ActionLink with "name" parameter as UrlParameter in MapRoute :

```
foreach (var c in Model.NavCategories)
{                        
      <li>@Html.ActionLink(c.Name, "Category", "Home", new { c.ID, Name = c.Name.ToHyphenate() }, null)</li>
}
```

I have an extension method to insert dash between url words too :

```
    public static string ToHyphenate(this string request)
    {
        return request.Replace(" ", "-");
    }
```

In RouteConfig I have this :

```
        routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Category",
                url: "Category/{id}/{name}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Category", id = UrlParameter.Optional, name = UrlParameter.Optional },                    
        );
```

navigating works fine and in the address bar the words are in correct format seprated with dash, but when you see View Source of Page, all urls generated in this format :

```
<a href="/category/1/%d8%ae%d9%88%d8%af%d8%b1%d9%88">
<a href="/category/2/%d8%a8%d8%a7%d9%86%da%a9%d8%8c%">
```

I want urls in same format shown in address bar in view source like this:

```
<a href="/category/1/my-category-name-one">
<a href="/category/2/my-category-name-two">
```

I have too many links, so is there any global way to avoid this?

Thanks for any assistance...

Comment: Url encoding shouldn't affect the hyphens. It looks like something else is going on. In fact, the sample "encoded" strings you posted - for example,  "%d8%ae%d9%88%d8%af%d8%b1%d9%88" - look like UTF-8 encodings of Arabic strings.

Comment: @Peter : yes, my app is in Persian Lang , I added utf-8 to globalization section in web.config and charset=utf-8 to meta tag of _Layout :content="text/html; charset=utf-8" , but not worked